# in ViewPager my Fragment's Adaptor is somthing like this. i want it to be an arraylist instead

Tags: java, android

for first: I used this adaptor for crating my Fragments and it works well.but i want use Array List for making them.
second: I have about 600 Fragments in different ViewPager do you have any idea how can I reduce some code?

```
    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    //*******************
   //*********************
  //********************* I want this dynamic (using ArrayList)
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment

                return Word1.newInstance("Word # 1",1);
            case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
                return Word2.newInstance("Word # 2",2);
            case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
                return Word3.newInstance("Word # 3",3);
            case 3: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
                return Word4.newInstance("Word # 4",4);

            default:
return Empty.newInstance("Word");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create pager adapter like this

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}
```

}

use it like this in your activity

```
 PagerAdapter mPagerAdapterExam = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);

    mPagerAdapterExam.addFragment(new CurrentOrdersFragment(), "Current Orders");
    mPagerAdapterExam.addFragment(new PastOrdersFragment(), "Past Orders");

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapterExam);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```